# How to turn on email forwarding with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, gmail, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

A brief description of the project: I am looking to toggle the email forwarding option in the settings of one of my gmail accounts through a google script. This will be a function I would like to call every night between certain hours forwarding my mail from main_email@gmail to secondary_email@gmail.

I am having a difficult time finding the easiest way to toggle this through a google script. The simplest solution seems to be described here where they use an HTTP request. However in all honesty I don't completely understand how it all works, much less if it is the simplest way.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateAutoForwarding

The code that I try and run on the gmail account to enable/disable email forwarding is the following:

```
function updateForwarding() {
    var userID = "main_email@gmail.com"
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + userID + "/settings/autoForwarding", {
        method: 'put',
        enabled: true,
        emailAddress: "secondary_email@gmail.com",
        disposition: "leaveInInbox"
    });

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

However I get the following error:

> Request failed for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/main_email@gmail.com/settings/autoForwarding
>   returned code 401. Truncated server response: { "error": { "errors": [
>   { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login
>   Required", "locationType": "header", ... (use muteHttpExceptions
>   option to examine full response) (line 4, file "Code")

I recognize this is shows I need to provide credentials for making the request, but I don't understand how I would do that. I read on the tutorial (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) I need to authorize my app with gmail and get an API key, so I have gone to the google developers console to create that. However, I have no idea how to authenticate or make the call through a Google script after a few hours of google.

Here are the key and secret I was given:
[image]

**Is this the easiest solution to toggle gmail forwarding?** If so, how do I authenticate my call? If not, what is the easiest solution to being able to toggle my gmail forwarding off/on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass oAuth token in header information

```
   function updateForwarding() {
        var userID = "main_email@gmail.com";
        var header = {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
         }
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + userID + "/settings/autoForwarding", {
            method: 'put',
            enabled: true,
            headers: header, 
            emailAddress: "secondary_email@gmail.com",
            disposition: "leaveInInbox"
        });

        Logger.log(response.getContentText());

    }
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I got a different error this time! Error 403, insufficient permissions. Looking at other SO articles it seems like the most common solution is to change userID to 'me', but it still results in the same error. Any idea what I should do to fix that?

Comment: Hi @Ritz, can you explain why you choose to use HTTP Request instead of the method provide by the Gmail API? For example, why not use Gmail.Users.Settings.updateForwarding()? Also, when I have OAuth, service account, and domain-wide delegation setup, I can't get it to work by using the methods to update settings of other users in the domain. I got "GoogleJsonResponseException: Not Found" error". It only works with HTTP Request. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the authorization section of https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateAutoForwarding, you need to use OAuth with the given scopes to make that call, not just an API key. You appear to have a client id, but you need to plug this into a library to handle the OAuth process for you. The OAuth process will then give you a Bearer token to add to your request (although most OAuth libraries will handle this for you).

It looks like https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2 is the current recommened way to do this if you're using UrlFetchApp (based on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).